# Multiple direction requests take more time after multiple calls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say you have a map to display KmlLayer objects on it, with toggle checkbox for each KmlLayer object, located in a panel.

```
var Province = new google.maps.LatLng(47.112754, -70.815223);
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {zoom:7,center:Province} );
```

And you store in KML files a limited number of routes, to optimize the speed of the map.

Direction's requests are made using Google Maps API v3.

And let's say you have a page containing a Google Map in a hidden div, and you make Direction requests through this API.
The array 'waypoints' holds the coordinates of each start and end point of each polyline needed.

```
var geo_coords = ''; // holds the results
var y; // counter
var delay_per_request = 1000; // default delay in milliseconds between requests
var current_delay = delay_per_request; // current delay between requests

function calcRoute(start,end) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var request = {
         origin: start,
         destination: end,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
         // Error?
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {

            document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML += "<br>" + start + "/" + end
               + "("+status+") :: Interval:"+current_delay+"ms";
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

            if (current_delay < 2600) {
               current_delay += 200;   
            }
            if (current_delay >= 1600) {
               delay_per_request = 1600;
            }

            retry++;

            if (retry < 20) {
               calcRoute(start,end);
            } else {
               document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML += "<br>The script stopped running after "+retry+" retries"
                  + " sur " + start + "/" + end + "("+status+") :: Interval:"+current_delay+"ms";
            }

         // Positive result?
         } else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var myRoute = response.routes[0].overview_path;

            for (i in myRoute) {
               if (myRoute[i] != undefined) {
                  geo_coords += myRoute[i].lat() + "," + myRoute[i].lng() + "_";
               }
            }   

            geo_coords += "!";
            document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML += "<br><font color=\"green\">" + start + "/" + end
               + "("+status+") :: Interval:"+current_delay+"ms</font>"; 
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

            current_delay = delay_per_request;
            retry = 0;

            Next(); 
         }
      }); 
   },current_delay);
}

function Next() {
   if (y <= waypoints.length) {
      destination = "from:" + waypoints[y] + " to:" + waypoints[y + 1];
      geo_desc += description[y] + " => " + description[y+1] + "|";
      calcRoute(waypoints[y],waypoints[y+1]);
      y = y +2;
   } else {
      document.getElementById("information").setAttribute('value',geo_coords);   
      document.getElementById("show_debug_text").setAttribute('value',geo_desc); 
      document.getElementById("error").setAttribute('value',document.getElementById('error_text').innerHTML);
      document.forms["kml"].submit();
   }
}  

Next();
```

My question is the following:
*Has anyone noticed that Google lower the priority of your requests after you made some request in batch?*
The more request you do, the bigger is the number of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response you get, the bigger is the delay between requests before you have a successful result, and the bigger is the number of requests before you have a successful result.

*Is there any workaround or any reason?*
**(I know I should use the Direction API Webservice to make my requests.)**
Thank you!

Comment: I think you would be better off asking this on the GIS overflow site. In any case I read a while back that Google throttles the number of requests made to its map servers depending on the number and I think if the number of requests reaches a certain point, you have to pay but its generally in the tens of thousands.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I will give it a try but I will keep the question here also.

Comment: The geocoder is subject to a quota and a rate limit to prevent abuse.  The actual rate limit may vary with the server load.

Comment: Is it the same kind of rate limit for the Direction API webservice?   I mean, is the server lowering the priority more and more after each request?

Comment: The quota and rate limits are AFAIK the same for both services.  I don't know what you mean by "is the server lowering the priority more and more after each request?"  I don't think "priority" has anything to do with it.  If you do some research, the general impression is (like the geocoder) you can do some number of requests quickly, then after that the service will be throttled to stay under the rate of "quota/24 hrs", but the details of the implementation are not published, probably change periodically, and probably depend on server load.

Comment: Does a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response count in the quota?